# Resizing nested std::vectors

Tags: c++, memory, stl, openmp

If I have:

`std::vector<std::vector<double> > vec`

Say I allocate space for each vec[0], vec[1], ... vec[vec.size()-1].

If I were to call:

`vec[3].resize(100)`

Is there a possibility that the vectors allocated before or after `vec[3]` will get repositioned?

The reason I ask is that I have a nested vector as shown above in an openmp section. Each thread controls `vec[threadnum]`. There are some resizes these threads do. I'm wondering if it's possible for one thread to resize `vec[thread]` which will cause others to get potentially shifted.

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No other vectors are modified when you perform resize (or call any other method) of a vector.

In fact, when you call a method of an object, other unrelated objects do not change their state.

The fact that we have here vector of vectors may be confusing if we imagine that all vectors store their data in common contiguous memory block. But that's not the case. Each vector has its own memory area, and each vector can reallocate memory independently (and "parent" vector doesn't know about the relocation at all).

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to hear. I also thought this was potentially possible since vectors store their data contiguously as you mentioned. As a side question, what is stored contiguously in the parent vector? Is the the pointers to the child vectors which are stored contiguously?

Comment: @jucestain It's the "child" `vector` objects themselves which are stored contiguously in the parent vector. However, note that this does not mean the child `vector`s' *data* all being in one block. It depends on implementation, but most likely, a `vector` object itself just stores some pointers to heap-allocated data. This way, the parent vector's data would be a contiguous array of groups of pointers, each of which would point to its own separate block of contiguous memory (for one child `vector`'s data).